# Convert configuration file into variables and convert forward slash to backslash

Tags: batch-file

I have a configuration file which I need for my bash script which has a layout:

```
A=C:/Example1/A
B=C:/Example2/B
C=C:/Example3/C
```

I want to use the same configuration file for my windows batch file. I need to convert the above file into variables which I have done using:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (test.txt) do (set "%%x")
```

How do I go about converting this file into variables while also converting all the forward slashes into backslashes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

add after your `for` line,

```
for /f "delims==" %%x in (q888.txt) do call set "%%x=%%%%x:/=\%%"
```

or, as a replacement for your existing `for`,

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%x in (q888.txt) do set "%%x=%%y"&call set "%%x=%%%%x:/=\%%"
```

(I used a file called `q888.txt` for testing)

The first smply executes a substitution, using a parsing trick. The second combines the set and substitution into one cascaded command  by tokenising on `=` into `%%x` and `%%y`

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with the following batch code:

```
@echo off
if not exist "test.txt" goto :EOF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ("test.txt") do (
    if not "%%~J" == "" (
        set "Value=%%~J"
        set "Value=!Value:/=\!"
        set "_%~n0_%%~I=!Value!"
    )
)

echo The variables set from file are:
echo/
set "_%~n0_"
echo/
pause

endlocal
```

The batch file first checks if the file to process exists in current directory at all. The batch file processing is exited with a jump to predefined label `EOF` (end of file, requires enabled extensions which are enabled by default) in case of the file `test.txt` does not exist at all.

Next the file is read line by line with skipping empty lines and lines starting with a semicolon by command **FOR** which splits each line up into two strings.

The first string left of first equal sign is assigned to loop variable `I`. Everything right of first equal sign is assigned next loop variable `J` according to ASCII table.

The **IF** condition in the loop checks if a value is also defined for a variable. The value is assigned to an environment variable on which a string substitution is executed using delayed expansion to replace all `/` by `\`.

Then the modified value is assigned to an environment variable with a name starting with `_`, the name of the batch file, one more underscore and the string assigned to loop variable `I` read from the file.

For demonstration the variables with their values are finally output before the local variables are discarded on execution of last command **ENDLOCAL**.

I strongly recommend not assigning the values read from the file directly to environment variables whose name is completely also read from the file as this makes the batch file easy to manipulate by just modifying the contents of the text file. For example `path=C:\Temp` in text file would otherwise result in `set "Path=C:\Temp"` and from this point of batch file execution the running Windows command process would not find anymore any standard executable in directories defined by default in environment variable `PATH` like `%SystemRoot%\System32`.

A second variant which incorporates answer posted by [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo) with above batch code:

```
@echo off
if not exist "test.txt" goto :EOF
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ("test.txt") do if not "%%~J" == "" set "_%~n0_%%~I=%%~J" & call set "_%~n0_%%~I=%%_%~n0_%%~I:/=\%%"

echo The variables set from file are:
echo/
set "_%~n0_"
echo/
pause

endlocal
```

The advantage of this variant is that delayed expansion is not needed for this solution which makes it possible to correct process also lines from file containing 1 or more exclamation marks on which first variant fails. And it is also a little bit faster, not noticeable faster for a human, but nevertheless a bit faster.

In both batch code blocks `_%~n0_` can be replaced by (nearly) anything including also nothing although that is not recommended. Using just an underscore would be also possible as there are no environment variables defined by default by Windows which start with an underscore.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~n0` (name of argument 0 - the batch file name - without path and without file extension).
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to let the `~f` FOR variable modifier put the full path in canonical form (including conversion of forward slashes to back slashes). I use the DELIMS and TOKENS options to split each line into the variable name and path so that I can apply the `~f` to the path. It is important to use `tokens=1*` instead of `tokens=1,2` just in case the path includes a `=` character.

```
for /f "delims== tokens=1*" %%A in (test.txt) do (set "%%A=%%~fB")
```

Note, however, that this strategy only works if your "test.txt" already contains full, absolute paths. If the file contains relative paths, then the `~f` modifier will add drive and or folder values from the current directory to turn the relative path into an absolute path.

Comment: @Bob - If this question fully answered your question, and you deem it to be the best answer, then you should formally accept the answer by clicking on the check mark in the upper left corner.